# How to withdraw PART of the Smart Contract's balance into an account?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, transfer, smartcontracts, ether

I have looked through many similar questions but they only address transferring the entirety of the smart contract's balance to the personal account, and it is done like this:

> msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

What I am trying (and failing) to figure out is how to transfer part of the balance. Eg. If the contract contains 3 ether, I only want to transfer 1. And I want to be able to specify the amount to be transferred every time I use the function. I am not posting my code because nothing I have tried works and it is pretty much guesswork.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public {
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
}
```

Withdraws the amount specified with `amount` variable. No need to check the total balance of the contract because if you try to withdraw more than total balance it will revert.

Comment: it would be a good practice to check if contract has that amount of token before transferring.

Comment: "it would be a good practice to check if contract has that amount of token before transferring" Why?

Comment: I mean write a require statement. So in case of error save some gas

Comment: I suppose it depends on what the function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As Iftivar Taz mentioned if you are practicing to try `msg.sender.transfer(amount)`. Try it with amount of 0 and it will probably work. Obviously your practicing contract won't have more than zero eths.